# Verifying a signature of an EFI binary

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I'm exploring UEFI secure boot and want to verify the certificates of the signed binaries.

The code below shows there are indeed some signatures present:

```
sbverify --list  $BOOT/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
warning: data remaining[1171248 vs 1334816]: gaps between PE/COFF sections?                   
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Windows UEFI Driver Publisher
   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
 - subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011
   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation Third Party Marketplace Root
```

I want to verify that signature using a totally wrong certificate, and am expecting the verification to fail.
In the steps below I create a random certificate and attempt to verify the binary signature with it:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out random-private-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key random-private-key.pem -out random-certificate.pem -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=My Organization/OU=My Unit/CN=mydomain.com"
sbverify --cert random-certificate.pem  $BOOT/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

# Output:
# warning: data remaining[1171248 vs 1334816]: gaps between PE/COFF sections?
# Signature verification OK
```

This is either a:

- false positive - no way the binary is signed by the just created random cert
- I'm misunderstanding the `sbverify` flags
- Bug in `sbverify`

Does anyone know a method for confirming the signature of an EFI binary?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things with `sbverify`:

- List & compare all issuers for *.efi executables, and other signed code like the Linux kernel:

```bash
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify --list /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grubx64.efi
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /serialNumber=5561017/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=US/ST=Florida/O=AlmaLinux OS Foundation
   issuer:  /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
 - subject: /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
   issuer:  /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing Root R46
 - subject: /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing Root R46
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services
```

```bash
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify --list /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-477.27.2.el8_8.x86_64
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /serialNumber=5561017/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=US/ST=Florida/O=AlmaLinux OS Foundation
   issuer:  /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
 - subject: /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing CA EV R36
   issuer:  /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing Root R46
 - subject: /C=GB/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo Public Code Signing Root R46
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services
```

- Verify the signature

```bash
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grubx64.efi
Signature verification OK
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-477.27.2.el8_8.x86_64
Signature verification OK
```

Listing the common name of the issuers, without their public key fingerprint, does not help us resolve trust issues. Neither does the `--cert <certfile>` argument.

The verification I suggest would be to download the signing certificate from [Sectigo](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-Intermediate-Certificates) and use that to compare it to the embedded certificate. Alas!

```bash
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify --cert sectigo-ev.crt /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grubx64.efi
Signature verification OK
[root@alma8-vm admin]# sbverify --cert bogus.crt /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grubx64.efi
Signature verification OK
```

We are not the only ones having these concerns, the developer did not respond to https://groups.io/g/sbsigntools/message/57